# Android SQLite two columns constraint

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a table like this

```
table:
    boolean field
    string field
```

I want to set a constraint which says that if the boolean field is True then the string field must not be NULL, but if the boolean field is False, the string field can be anything ?

Is that possible?

Thank you

Comment: .... how ? Your answer is very vague

Comment: This is comment, not an answer. You asked "is that possible?", I said yes it.   Better you read how to ask question >> http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, note that according to the [SQLite docs](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html):

> SQLite does not have a separate Boolean storage class. Instead, Boolean values are stored as integers 0 (false) and 1 (true).

With that in mind, assuming your boolean is named `bool_column` and your string is `string_column`:

`CHECK (bool_column = 0 OR (bool_column = 1 AND string_column IS NOT NULL))`

Comment: Where do I put the CHECK clause ?

Comment: @mp3por You would create your table using something like: `CREATE TABLE table_name (boolean_field BOOLEAN, string_field TEXT, CHECK (bool_column = 0 OR (bool_column = 1 AND string_column IS NOT NULL)))`